# How is it possible?

Tags: riddle, situation, no-computers

I have been captured, then shot, framed and hung.  But luckily,  I am not dead.

How is it possible?

**Disclaimer: this puzzle is inspired by real world observation, so no alien lifeforms, super heroes or undead involved.  There is a perfectly normal logical explanation to it.**

And please, no computers.

Comment: You are a bank robber that was captured by greed, shot in the leg during a failed heist, framed by your co-robbers, and then hung out to dry.

Comment: I think this would be much more interesting/challenging without the "framed" part.

Comment: At first I thought about a picture, however, I don't like the idea that "I am not dead". Also, in medieval times when a rope was broken and hangman survived, it was considered as a sign of God and he was set free.

Comment: @Voitcus: [citation needed]

Comment: You say there are "no alien lifeforms, super heroes or undead involved", yet the solution involved a [spoiler] saying things about itself in the first person...

Comment: @ruakh Yes, I don't have any source for this other than my memory ("I once read about it")

Comment: You are obviously Rasputin

Comment: @xnor My solution doesn't! :-D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are a

> picture

You are captured

> Captured on a camera

then shot,

> Take a picture

framed and hung

> Frame a picture and hang it.

I am not dead.

> You are an object. You are whole and not broken, so you are not "dead".

Comment: Technically the answer isn't alive, so wouldn't it have to be dead?

Comment: @AggieKidd In the case of an object, "dead" might refer to being whole and not broken.

Comment: And there's the perfectly logical explanation. Well done.

Comment: How is a picture captured on camera and then shot? Those are synonyms for the same action, I believe.

Comment: @AggieKidd No, because things that aren't alive don't have to be dead. Not all things have all properties. Doesn't it sound funny to you to say that a picture is 'dead'?

Answer (score 10):

I saw mmking's answer and comes up with an alternative:

Is it:

> You are a... moment?

You are captured

> The moment is captured

then shot,

> via camera

framed and hung

> As a picture

I am not dead

> The moment is 'alive' as a picture now

Comment: I suppose that will work too. +1.

Answer (score 10):

Another alternative:

> you are an actor.

Captured

> by the allure of the film industry,

shot

> in an action film,

framed

> in a detective film,

and hung

> in a western film.

You're not dead:

> you're rolling in money from all these films you've appeared in!